# Add Content Exclusively to a Custom Post Type Feed

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, rss

### Introduction

If I wanted to add some content at the end of an RSS feed entry, I could write something like this:

```
// quick PHP 5.3+ example
add_filter('the_content', function($content) {
    // If this is not a feed, leave now.
    if ( !is_feed() ) return $content;

    // Add content to the feed entry.
    $content .= 'Thank you for subscribing to the feed.';
});
```

### What I Want to Do

The above works fine; however, that will add "Thank you for subscribing to the feed." to every feed entry. If I wanted to add that line only if it's a feed for a certain custom post type, how would I do that?

For example, if I had a custom post type called `'books'`, I could access the feed link for that by going to `example.com/feed/?post_type=books`. So instead of saying, `'Thank you for subscribing to the feed.'` I would like to say, `'Thank you for subscribing to the books feed.'` Likewise with feeds of other post types.

---

I figured that passing an argument into `is_feed( $feeds )` could be the answer, but the [codex documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_feed) doesn't seem to be very clear to me on what to pass exactly. It just says, "feed types"?

> $feeds
>   (array/string) (optional) Feed type(s) to check.
>   Default: None

Is that a URL to a feed? A slug of something perhaps? "RSS 2.0" etc.? (Or maybe that has nothing to do with my problem.)

The only information I can seem to find is how to access the custom post type's feed in the first place (e.g. `example.com/feed/?post_type=books`)---not how to add content exclusively to that feed.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you can use more specific `the_content_feed` hook, so your code doesn't have to run in unrelated contexts.

The "type" refers to *feeds* (not posts), so it would be something like `rss2` and it will be same across post types.

It is a little unobvious, but feeds are also kind of a Loop, same as on front end. So same APIs typically work just fine.

Your check can be something like `if ( 'books' === get_post_type() )`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much. I didn't know about that hook or the feeds being a Loop.